# Why does this promise not go to the next "then"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

So I have this code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("apiCall", function(request, response) {

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        // API call 1
    }).catch(function(error) {
        /// Only perform this if the first call fails

        // Return valid json here, to mock the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest below
        return Parse.Promise.as({"data": "this is an expected JSON"});

        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            // API call 2
        });
    }).then(
        function(httpResponse) {
            /// This should perform after call 1, or call 2 if call 1 failed

            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                // API call 3
            });
        }
    ).catch(
        function(error) {
            console.log('FAIL');
            return response.error(error);
        }
    );
});
```

I expected call 3 to be performed even if Call 1 failed, but apparently it does not, it performs the first `catch` block, but then it performs the last `catch` block. I thought I caught the error properly when I return a new promise in the `catch` block?

Comment: You are catching the error properly, and returning a promise out of a `catch` slaves the `catch`'s promise to that promise. So if your `then` handler isn't being called, it's because things are quite as they're shown above, or the promise returned by `Parse.Promise.as(...)` is either rejecting or never resolving. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: use async/await , far easier

Comment: Sigh, I had a stupid unknown reference error :/ Code like this works as I expected

Comment: FYI it looks to me from the code written here that call 3 is just also failing. You probably tried to access that string like it was JSON.

Comment: @JakeT. Correct, I realised that half an hour after I fixed this issue. I’m not usually working with JavaScript, so I am not very good at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you should have only one catch block for each Promise chain.

You could refactor your code with async/await blocks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("apiCall", async function(request, response) {

    let response = null;
    try {
        response = await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            // API call 1
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({"data": "this is an expected JSON"});

        response = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            // API call 2
        });
    }
    try {
        // Use response variable here
        let response2 = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            // API call 3
        });
        return response2;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('FAIL');
        return response.error(error);
    }
});
```

If you want to stick with Promise chain, you can also do this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("apiCall", function(request, response) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            // API call 1
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            /// Only perform this if the first call fails

            // Return valid json here, to mock the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest below
            console.log({"data": "this is an expected JSON"});

            Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                // API call 2
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                reject(error);
            })
        })
    }).then(
        function(httpResponse) {
            /// This should perform after call 1, or call 2 if call 1 failed

            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                // API call 3
            });
        }
    ).catch(
        function(error) {
            console.log('FAIL');
            return response.error(error);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Which JavaScript version is this? async/await is not available in my code.

Comment: to be accurate, ES6 is also known as ES2015 - `async`/`await` didn't make it into the spec until 2 versions later, ES2017

Comment: `you should have only one catch block for each Promise chain` - but that wasn't the problem, and there is nothing wrong with having more than one catch in a chain, in fact, it can be quite useful

Comment: You can have multiple error blocks as long as you are handling it properly.  Just be aware that if you don't return anything from an error handler, it's returning an empty resolved promise that will get passed to the next link in the chain. Took me a while to figure that one out, resulting in my confusion as to why my functions weren't terminating properly.

Comment: @vrwim What version of Node are you using? They added `async`/`await` support in v7. The [latest LTS release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release), released last May, is based on v8. Once you can, I would suggest getting to know them, they are really useful for writing more succinct, easier to read code.